# Matlab: set default values for GUI edit text and use them in push button callback

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, setdefault

I'm trying to initialize a GUI (built with GUIDE) with default values and then, if the user does not change the defaults, use these values in a function triggered by a push button callback.

To do this, inside the `_CreateFcn`, I first store the default values within the `handles`, then set the default of the GUI with `set(hObject, ...)` and finally update the guidata with `guidata(hObject, handles);`

If the user changes the value, I store the updated value in the handles inside the `_Callback` function reading the value with `get(hObject, ...)` and updating the guidata with `guidata(hObject, handles);`

When the button is pushed, inside the button `_Callback` function, I extract the value from the `handles`.

What happen is the following:

- if the user **does not** change the value on the GUI and simply pushes the button, what I read out from the variable stored in the handles is **not** the value of the variable, but the actual *handle* to the variable (for example: `27.0098876953125`)
- If, on the other hand, the user **does** change the value before pushing the button, then everything works fine and I get the actual variable value.

What am I missing?

## Update

Following *oro777* comment I've added the rest of the code for better analysis. I've also tried with a more recent (R2015b) version of MATLAB and the result is the same, with the difference that now the `disp` inside the button callback function shows the entire handle structure instead of just the id:

```
UIControl (ampmin) with properties:

          Style: 'edit'
         String: '1'
BackgroundColor: [1 1 1]
       Callback: @(hObject,eventdata)GUI('ampmin_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
          Value: 0
       Position: [15.6000 14.6154 10.2000 1.6923]
          Units: 'characters'

Use get to show all properties
```

I've also noticed the following:
 - If I start the `.fig` file everything works fine
 - If I push the `run` button on the `.m` file, the strange behavior described above occurs

Here is the code:

```
function varargout = GUI2(varargin)
% GUI2 MATLAB code for GUI2.fig
%      GUI2, by itself, creates a new GUI2 or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUI2 returns the handle to a new GUI2 or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUI2('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUI2.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      GUI2('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUI2 or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI2 before GUI2_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to GUI2_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI2 Options on GUIDE Tools menu.  Choose "GUI2 allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help GUI2

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 14-Aug-2015 10:39:46

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @GUI2_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @GUI2_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before GUI2 is made visible.
function GUI2_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUI2 (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for GUI2
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes GUI2 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = GUI2_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in startAnalysis.
function startAnalysis_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to startAnalysis (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

disp(handles.ampmin)





function ampmin_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ampmin (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of ampmin as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of ampmin as a double
handles.ampmin = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function ampmin_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ampmin (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

handles.ampmin = 1.0;
disp(handles.ampmin)
set(hObject, 'String', num2str(handles.ampmin))

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. I guess the rest of your code is messing up something.

Comment: You have problem because you **overwrite** the handle with your custom value. You should not write anything on top of `handle.ampmin`, this is set by `GUIDE` to retain the handle of the `uicontrol`. If you want to store data in the `handles` structure, define a new custom field for it : `handles.ampminValue = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Hoki, that was the problem. Since I didn't see any direct reference to `handles.ampmin` I didn't think it would be used to store the handle, but looking at the actual `.fig` exported code, it became apparent that indeed that's were the `uicontrol` handle is stored.